# Which Git files to remove

Tags: android

I want GitHub to stop tracking my local repository. And after that upload it again as a fresh copy. Which files will I remove inside an Android folder? Or is there a command?
Thanks.

Edited:
I'm on Windows 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete the `.git` folder in your project root, or if you want to export only what is under source control you could do:

```
git archive --format zip --output /path/to/save/exported.zip master
```

Edit: If you are on Windows you will need `Show Hidden Files and Folders` enabled in order to see the `.git` folder.  `Start --> Control Panel --> Appearance and Personalization --> Folder Options --> View tab, under Advanced Settings click Show hidden files, folders, and drives`

Comment: There is no .git folder in my android project folder.

Comment: Make sure you have `Show Hidden Files` enabled if you are on Windows.

Comment: ^ wrong, every folder starts with "." is hidden in mac ox/linux

Comment: I said nothing about Mac/Linux

Comment: Thanks @antew it worked. I forgot it was a hidden folder. Thanks.